# exit throught javascript code from android app (Intel XDK crosswalk android build)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

I'm creating javascript app for android Intel xdk ***crosswalk for android*** build.
I'm unable to exit from my app using following commands:

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

and

```
navigator.device.exitApp();
```

How to close an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works for me. You need the cordova.js script tag. The intel xdk inserts the cordova.js when it builds the app, you don't need to put the actual file in your project directory.

Exitapp had a bug that is fixed in Crosswalk 4.32.76.3. If you are launching the app from the debug tab, then it will be using an older crosswalk that does not work. You can use the newer crosswalk by building the app, and in the bottom of the details page select the canary option which is labeled Crosswalk 4.32.76.4

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>PhoneGap</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript"">

        function onLoad()
        {
              document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }

        function exitFromApp()
         {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
         }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
   <button name="buttonClick" onclick="exitFromApp()">Click Me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx, my problem was in absence of cordova.js file.

Comment: Have another question now.. Where can I get cordova.js file for crosswalk?
The one I've included raised errors: _cordovaNative is missing... but the exit functions work

Comment: You don't need to put the file in the directory. XDK puts it there for you. I added a clarification to the answer.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same but for android build and not for crosswalk this time? The same procedure doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included cordova.js after intelxdk.js -- and note that this exit function only works on Android, it will not work with iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain where should I include cordova.js exactly? Also I don't have intelxdk.js included in my code. I just builded apk file from my html/js code using Intel xdk crosswalk build and that's it. All works fine except EXIT app and SAVE files to disc functionality.